# OpenGLES can't set render

Tags: java, opengl

As a beginner, I am following the "Building an OpenGLES environment" docs. I just want to draw a grey screen. I've written every step as suggested but Eclipse still gives me an error in the MyGLSurfaceView class and in MyRenderer class. Here they are

Main activity

```
package com.example.testopengl;

import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class OpenGLES20Activity extends Activity {

    private GLSurfaceView mGLView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        mGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
        setContentView (mGLView);

}


}
```

MyGLSurfaceView class

```
package com.example.testopengl;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;

public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {


    public MyGLSurfaceView (Context context) {
        super (context);

        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

        setRenderer(new MyRenderer());

        setRenderMode (GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    }

}
```

MyGLRenderer class

```
package com.example.testopengl;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.opengl.EGLConfig;
import android.opengl.GLES20;

public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    public void onSurfaceCreated (GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame (GL10 unused) {
    GLES20.glClear (GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);    
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged (GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    }

}
```

Errors pops in MyGLSurfaceView class at this line setRenderer (new My Renderer());

and in MyGLRenderer class at public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer

Answer (score 0):

The methods you're using in your renderer are **static** methods: you need to do the following to make your code work:

```
import static android.opengl.GLES20.*
```

Then you can use these static functions without qualification:

```
public void onSurfaceChanged (GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height); // this is a static method
}
```

Comment: Nope, imports are ok. The error on MyGLRenderer says: GLSurfaceView.Renderer cannot be resolved to a type (same thing on myRenderer - MyRenderer cannot be resolved to a type) .

Comment: Did you try a project clean? Are your Java build paths set properly?

Comment: Yes, the project is clean and paths are ok. Still the same problem.

Comment: I really can't understand why GLSurfaceView.Render can't access render method. Other Opengles project work just fine.